# How to access a variable defined within a sheet inside a Form

Tags: excel, vba, variables, global

I have a global variable defined at the top of my sheet
Public AddYear As Boolean

I can access it within the worksheet fine, but I cannot access it with a Form that I have.  why is this?  I thought that if I declared the variable outside the function, it would be visible in the whole workbook.

I also moved the declaration to the ThisWorkbook section, to no avail.

I also tried the declaration at the top of my Form, also to no avail.

Please help...

Comment: You need to declare public variables in a standard module (in the VB Editor -> Insert -> Module), not in a worksheet module.

Comment: Thank you... this solved my problem...  I knew it had to be something simple. :-)

Answer (score 1):

A variable defined in a sheet code module is a member of that particular object's "class module", so to access it you need to prepend the sheet codename, or a reference to the sheet object itself:

```
Debug.Print Sheet1.YourVarNameHere
```

or

```
Debug.Print Sheets("Sheet1").YourVarNameHere
```

or even

```
Debug.Print CallByName(Sheets("Sheet1"), "YourVarNameHere", VbGet)
```

Comment: All three suggestions give me a runtime error.

Comment: @MattN. - what runtime error do you get?  You might consider posting a new question with more details.